# Is there a way to use a MediaFire download link on multiple devices?

Tags: batch-file, download

Let me break it down: I'm writing a BATCH program that needs to download a file from MediaFire, and it works 100% on my computer. However, I had my friend test it and the program was unable to download the file every time he tried. When the program was run, cURL launched, but never started the download. I tried it right after, and it still worked for me.

So here's my question: How do I get a link for the download that will work on anyone's computer, if they were to download and use it?

Here's the code snippit that downloads the file: (I'm new to BATCH so it's a little rough)

```
curl -o mods.rar http://download1503.mediafire.com/rkg79lmghohg/5xlv4nm1nup0ix6/mods.rar
```

Comment: I'd assume that they're not using Windows 10, Insider build 17063, and Windows 10 1803, or newer, prior to that, cURL wasn't included with the OS. They'll need to get a compatible version of cURL, or you'll need to find another way of downloading your RAR file.

Comment: From what they told me, the cURL appears and comes up with "Time remaining" and such, and then just stops and moves on. Not quite sure but that makes it sound like they at least had it. EDIT: Here's a pic, not mine but this is what he told me he saw. https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.addictivetips.com%2Fwindows-tips%2Fuse-curl-on-windows-10%2F&psig=AOvVaw3LBUsiiVK_5UnVy4uwW2tv&ust=1589586508917000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CAIQjRxqFwoTCODHka_FtOkCFQAAAAAdAAAAABAD

Comment: I'm sorry if I didn't guess what your friend told you! This is not a game, it's a technical forum, please make sure your question includes all of the information pertinent to potential responders, so that we don't waste our precious time trying to assist you. That said, your question body said "anyone's computer", not just your friends', so my advice is still valid!

Comment: Sorry! I'm not trying to waste anyone's time, but I'm new and literally just signed up to ask this. Question has been edited to include this information. Doesn't a new download generate a key? I know that it's probably not right, but if you click "repair your download" it generates a new key. Could it be that the key is only valid for one IP? I don't know much about how downloads work.

Comment: You're still talking about your friend's computer, not anyone's. But yes, mediafire is known to redirect to the repair download page. This means you'll have to allow them to do that themselves, or you'll have to re-upload the file to generate a new "download link" (file id), for your script.